# Why does the App Store think Xcode 4.2 is installed?

Tags: mac-appstore, xcode

I'm trying to upgrade Xcode from 4.1 to 4.2. 
However App Store thinks that it's already up to date, which it is not.

[image: screenshot of App Store]
[image: screenshot of Xcode]

I am a registered Mac and iOS developer. I don't think 4.2 is under NDA.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the XCode installer in /Applications, restart App Store. Now you will have an "Install" button for XCode. Download the installer and run it.

Comment: Ah, simple and elegant solution. Nice. Thank you for a quick solution.

Comment: Note that you have to go back to Xcode's page on the App Store from the search bar, Xcode 4.2 doesn't show up as an upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, chances are the installer is for Xcode 4.2. The App Store is a bit misleading, since it doesn't actually install Xcode, but downloads the installer and puts it in /Applications/Install Xcode.app. You still need to run the installer. The App Store knows nothing about if you've done that or not.